# PHP Amp/Parallel. Please give me example about parallel function with pool

Tags: multithreading, php-7.2, amphp, php-pthread

I have been stuck in my task about running functions in parallel. I has tried this library multi-threading [pthreads from krakjoe](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads), but I has limit knowledge about installations in ubuntu. I has tried this [amp/parallel](https://github.com/amphp/parallel/) instead and other [amphp](https://amphp.org). The [examples](https://github.com/amphp/parallel/blob/master/examples/worker-pool-simple.php) in github is running well enough, but I can't implement it by my style.

I'm not familiar with whatever [semantics](https://semver.org), if there are many example to do within this amp/parallel. I would be very happy.

> The problems

i need to run one function in parallel way, I want to read report from excel File, and bulk insert all the rows to database and this proccess needs two hours to be completed. And I want to repeat this functions in parallel way. How to bulk insert and read file Excel I have knowledge to do it.

Please give me some example, whenever from blogs, website, or github about parallel functions or multi-threading in php7.2.

Answer (score -4):

I have found worked installation pthreads on ubuntu, and I have done some experiment on it. 
This questions can be closed.